# rpy2 does not translate "_" into "."

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to read a csv file in Python using the function "read.csv" imported from R using rpy2.

```
r_read_csv = robjects.r['read.csv']
r_read_csv("initVar.csv", header = True, row_names = 1)
```

However, the code above returns an error with the message:

```
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
    unused argument (row_names = 1)
```

In R, the parameter's name is `row.names`. However, I cannot use a dot because its meaning is different in Python.

I thought that rpy2 translates "_" into ".". At least that's what I understood from their [documentation](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#getting-started). Apparently, I am wrong.

**Question**: How do I specify `row.names = 1` in this case?

Comment: As per https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html  `row_names = 1` even if `row.name=1` is not useful as it is the default behavior to take first column as name in the absence of column headers in first row. Drop it and try if you get your desired output.

Comment: "in the absence of column headers" - but I do have column headers (see header = True). So your advice doesn't apply in this case I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting error which I do reproduce! It appears `read.csv` in `rpy2` does not inherit its parent function, `read.table` and hence does not recognize *row_names* argument. However, you can use `read.table` making sure to specify defaults of `read.csv`:

```
read_tbl = robjects.r['read.table']

rdf = read_tbl("/path/to/data.csv", header = True, row_names = 1, sep = ",")
```

Similarly, if you use the `importr` approach for utils package:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
...
utils = importr("utils")

rdf = utils.read_table("/path/to/data.csv", header = True, row_names = 1, sep = ",")
```

---

However, neither below works in Python but does in R:

Python

```
read_csv = robjects.r['read.csv']
rdf = read_csv("/path/to/data.csv", row_names = 1)

utils = importr("utils")
rdf = utils.read_csv("/path/to/data.csv", row_names = 1)
```

R

```
df <- read.csv("/path/to/data.csv", row.names = 1)
```

Comment: thanks, works perfectly! if you could, i would very much appreciate if you could explain me how you proceeded in finding the answer? just how you thought about it and what steps you took. it would help me to find out the answer myself next time.

Comment: This is more knowledge and experience. Before anything, I knew `rpy2` converts period names with underscore. So first I tested `read.csv` with `robjects` and then `importr` to reproduce your issue on a dummy csv. Then, knowing `read.csv` is a wrapper to the `read.table` suite of functions, I tested `read.table` to find it does work. I reviewed the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) also to see `row.names` is not exposed as named param in `read.csv` to conclude `rpy2` does not inherit its parent caller.